# express получение запроса любого типа

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Чтобы получить запрос с `body: <json>`, нужно использовать `.use(express.json())`

Для текста аналогично `.use(express.text())`

Для xml уже нужно подключать библиотеку `express-xml-bodyparser`, `.use(xmlparser())`

Можно ли как-то без указаний `.use(<>)` принимать любые типы боди?

```
createProxyServer() {
    const logger = new ConsoleLoggerService('proxy-server');
    const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ changeOrigin: true });
    const app = express();

    app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
        logger.log(`Got request to ${req.path}, method=${req.method} `);

        next();
    });

    registerServiceController(app);

    app.all('*', async (req, res, next) => {
        const { path } = req;
        const proxyPath = findProxyPath(path);
        const proxyHost = proxyMap[proxyPath];

        if (proxyHost) {
            logger.log(`Path [${path}] will be proxying to [${proxyHost}] host`);

            proxy.web(req, res, {
                target: {
                    protocol: 'https:',
                    host: proxyHost,
                    port: 443,
                },
            });
        } else {
            logger.error(`Proxy mapping for [${path}] not found, request not proxied`);
        }
        next();
    })
        .use(express.json())
        .use(express.text())
        .use(express.raw({ type: 'application/pdf', limit: '10mb' }))
        .use(xmlparser())
        .all('*', async (req, res, next) => {
            const { path } = req;
            const proxyPath = findProxyPath(path);
            const proxyHost = proxyMap[proxyPath];
            await ProxyStorageService.saveRequest(req, proxyHost);
        });

    app.listen(PORT);

    logger.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
}
```

Comment: Запрос придет и без `use()`... Усложнится лишь последующая его обработка. А так все сделают функции промежуточной обработки.

Comment: если делать без ` .use(express.json())` - то body undefined при отправке json

Comment: Так это `express.json()` туда данные записывает. Он их вычитывает из запроса. Если есть желание - ты можешь научиться делать это самостоятельно...

Comment: Вот примеры такого чтения - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: Еще статейка... https://digitrain.ru/articles/276906/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то без указаний .use(<>) принимать любые типы боди?

Естественно... bodyParser.json() и им подобные просто возвращают обычный экспрессовский handlerFunction(req, res, next) который можно обернуть как тебе захочеться.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const parsers = {
    json: bodyParser.json(),
    urlencoded: bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}),
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if ('POST' !== req.method) {
        return next();
    }
    const contentType = String(req.get('Content-Type') || null);
    switch (true) {
        case contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1:
            parsers.json(req, res, next);
            break;
        case contentType.indexOf('application/x-www-form-urlencoded') !== -1:
            parsers.urlencoded(req, res, next);
            break;
        default:
            res.status(422).send("422 Unprocessable Entity");
    }
});

app.all("/endpoint", (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

test-index.http

```
### Post json
POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 18

{"hello": "world"}

### POST urlencoded
POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 20

hello=world&test=123

### POST another
POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint
Content-Type: uncnown/type
Content-Length: 15

This is an test
```